# Less processes css as invalid

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to use https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector with less. I'm wondering if there's a way to have less ignore a few lines and just add them as is to a css file.

`body! > .modal-trigger:checked { overflow: hidden; }` presents a **ParseError: Unrecognised input** error.

If you put `body! > .modal-trigger:checked { overflow: hidden; }` in a css file it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ignoring the whole line (which would require too cryptic tricks) you can ignore just the invalid character, e.g.:

```
@excl: !;
body@{excl} > .modal-trigger:checked {overflow: hidden}
```

Alternatively you can move all that non-CSS into a separate CSS file and include it with `(inline)` option so Less will just copy its contents w/o parsing:

```
@import (inline) "whatever.css";
```

Another alternative would be to use [CSS escaping](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#escaped-characters) but *only if* it is supported by the polyfill as well:

```
body\! > .modal-trigger:checked {overflow: hidden}
```

Comment: You my friend are amazing. Thank you so much. P.S. Thanks for including 3 different ways, you're awesome.